# Difference between find objective adjective vs. find that clause

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was wondering the difference of meaning the following sentences:

1. I found him interesting.
2. I found that he is interesting.

Comment: (1) is a reduction of _I found him to be interesting_, which refers to the speaker's personal emotional reaction to him. (2), with a _that_-clause instead of an infinitive, refers to an intellectual discovery of the speaker's, namely that he is an interesting person. This may mean the same as (1), but it does not require the speaker to find him interesting; it would be sufficient merely for the speaker to notice that others generally do.

Comment: Same meaning - different syntax. A few (not many) grammars analyse _him interesting_ in your example 1. as a 'small clause', so the whole can be paraphrased as your example 2. Syntactically, however, the constructions are very different. The overlap between the verbs entering into both constructions is relatively small, such that it is better and simpler to consider 1. as a complex-transitive clause and 2. as containing a subordinate clause.